# IP address regex python

Tags: python, regex, ip, analysis

I am having an issue with Regular expression, I need the most efficient regex that 
match IP address and in range of 255 only.

I tried this one "`ip_pattern = '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}'`" , but it does match even numbers over 255, such as 321.222.11.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
```

Comment: should it be like this "^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
" or how ??

Answer (score 1):

Use this Regex. It will match and check the IP range within 255.

\b(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]).(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]).(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]).(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])\b