# Parsing number from a group of strings Python

Tags: python

If a user inputs a strings with a IP address.
I want to extract only the IP 
For example:

```
Hello I am localhost 127.0.0.1
```

I want to get only ip "127.0.0.1" from the whole string, how can i do it?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IP address regex python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370552/ip-address-regex-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re` :

```
import re
result = re.findall("\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+", "Hello I am localhost 127.0.0.1")
```

Output :

```
['127.0.0.1']
```

Comment: how can we do same for the ports?

Comment: A port is a fixed 4 digit number, so "\d{4}" would do just fine. And, please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue. @AnandVyas

Comment: Thanks bro :D checking the code and will reply back.

Comment: Please note this will catch many invalid "ip addresses" `1.2.3.4444`, `999.999.999.999`, etc.

Comment: I know, but where do you see `1.2.3.4444` or `999.999.999.999` ? Give me one example and I will edit my answer. @TemporalWolf

Comment: `Call us at 1.800.555.5555` is a valid phone format, with 90 million results in google for `1.800.`. And I've seen `000.000.000.000` used as a dummy IP address. For his purposes it may not be relevant, but other people will see this answer: it's important to acknowledge limitations.

Comment: Hello both the bro's? can you help me in another thing :D?

Comment: Hello!
I have the first file.

> 1st.py
    
    `import 2nd
    code = "<?php $ip= '''+ip+''' $port='''+port+''' ?>"`

> 2nd.py

   ` ip = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 8080
   `
I want to use the variables from 2nd.py in 1st.py .. how can i do it?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex that matches IPv4 addresses:

```
(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])
```

You could use it like this

```
import re
regex = r"(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])"
print(re.search(regex, "string with an ip like 127.0.0.1 in it").group())
```