# Compare variable with regex variable

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I use a variable to save an ip like this, but I need to verify that it really has an ip format. The ip field does not always have to be a list.
I have this:

```py
ip=["8.8.8.8","8.8.8.6"] # List or only one element
reg_ip = r'(?:\d{1,3}\.)+(?:\d{1,3})'
filter_ip=re.findall(reg_ip,ip)
```

But the answer is as follows

```py
filter_ip= [u"8.8.8.8",u"8.8.8.6"]
```

And therefore does not meet the condition

```py
if ip == reg_ip:
```

How should I do it?

Comment: Looks like you need `re.search()` ?

Comment: if ip in filter_ip

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IP address regex python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370552/ip-address-regex-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
ip="8.8.8.8"
reg_ip = r'(?:\d{1,3}\.)+(?:\d{1,3})'
filter_ip=re.findall(reg_ip,ip)
if ip in reg_ip:
   pass
```

Comment: Mmm it works, but if the ip field is a list?
I have the following.
ip=8.8.8.8,8.8.8.6
filter_ip=[u"8.8.8.8", u"18.8.8.6"]

Comment: Nice, give to this answer is useful. I will check

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are checking if there any matches with Regex, so `.findall` will return you the number of matches

```
import re
ip=["8.8.8.8","8.8.8.6"]
reg_ip = re.compile(r'(?:\d{1,3}\.)+(?:\d{1,3})')
filter_ip = list(filter(reg_ip.search, ip))
if ip == filter_ip:
   print "All ip Matched!"
```

Recommend you to use `.search` if you have a single `ip` to check for as its faster and you need not need multiple matches.

Using `.search`

```
ip="8.8.8.8"
reg_ip = r'(?:\d{1,3}\.)+(?:\d{1,3})'
if re.search(reg_ip,ip):
    print "Matched !"
```

Comment: It could be the case that ip was a listing, and therefore filter_ip the same

Comment: It does not work, it does not enter the conditional when it is a list. 
The problem may be the format?

Comment: @DaniMartinez i expect it should work fine now. please check and confirm

Comment: The ip field does not always have to be a list.
I have this error: 'str' object has no attribute 'search'

Comment: @DaniMartinez Can you please edit your question with exact sample input and desired output? and the errors which you have. As you have always been changing the question each and every time :(